# ADEMPIERE - No Accounting Entries found in Posted Button of Physical Inventory

Tags: java, erp, adempiere

[image: Physical Inventory On Click of Posted Button, No Accounting Entries Found]

On creation of new product in Adempiere, and increasing inventory through Physical Inventory, the main issue I am facing is that no accounting entries are being posted, Can Anyone explain what is the cause of this problem?

I know this is related to Costing in Adempiere, but couldn't completely decode the Issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For application support rather than development support you'd probably be better asking questions like these in the Adempiere [forums](http://adempiere.net/web/guest/forums) or in their gitter [room](http://adempiere.net/web/guest/chat-on-line).

Adding new items like this can have costing issues okay.  Before it can post the accounting it needs to know what value to post, naturally.  Another popular problem when testing is that the *Period* is not **Open** [or perhaps even not created].

If you look in the menu `Performance Analysis->Accounting Rules->Unposted Documents` you can find your *Physical Inventory* document, click the **Posting Error** button and when it prompts to repost click **Cancel**. It should display the **Posting Error** which is stopping this document being posted.  This is a first step in finding your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Any stack trace error that you can show from the logs? Set the log level to FINE to see again. If there are no stack trace it probably is not a bug. Note that Accounts are posted only when there are transactions events such as Material Movement. Normal creation of records does not warrant any accounting consequences.
Things to check:

1. What is your SystemCongfiguraton setting for CLIENT ACCOUNTING?:
   Enable client Accounting -> D - Disabled (default) / Q - Queue (enabled to post by hand - queue documents for posterior processing) / I - Immediate (immediate post)
2. Can other accounts be posted? i.e. Invoice (Customer)

Comment: 1. System configuration is set to C. 
2. Invoice and Material Receipt have accounting entries, its just the case of Physical Inventory and Inventory Use that no entries are posted.
3. Also a point to note here, that if we create a new product and perform Physical inventory no accounting Entries are posted, but once Material receipt and Invoice are done , then if we try Physical Inventory, accounting Entries are there.